# How to get the distance between two postal codes

Tags: geolocation, geocoding

Is it possible to get the distance between two postal codes for free? I tried to google the answer but all I found is Google Maps API key which requires contacting sales or things like that.

Its feel a bit overkill to make billing accounts to Google just for getting the distance between two postal codes.

I'm building a SaaS app and I would like to show the estimated distance between place A and place B. This feature isn't essential but would be cool under some circumstances.

Is it possible to achieve this for free?

Comment: Yes. You can find a full list of post codes and their lat/long positions on the internet. You can then write a program that can calculate the distance between the 2 points. It's a fairly big task, but I have done it myself in the past so I know it is possible.

Comment: @musefan Thanks for the suggestion. I think I finally found all the necessary data of my own country (postal codes lat/long etc). Building the calculator program is the simplest part of this, lol.

Comment: I agree, getting the right data took a while to find... and I can't remember where I got it which is why I didn't recommend anything. I only did the UK, thankfully that was all I needed to do